# primary domain to subfolder without folder name in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, laravel-5.3

I've 2 websites

1. Shopping Website (Magneto 1)
2. Blogging website (Laravel)

and I've single domain for example http://www.shopnow.com/, so i need to set `.htaccess` file in root directory so that

1. http://www.shopnow.com   ==> public_html/shop
2. http://blog.shopnow.com  ==> public_html/blog

I've tried `.htaccess` in root folder as

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
# Change example.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?shopnow.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shopnow/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shopnow/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?shopnow.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /shopnow/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your apache's site configuration. Edit your post with it, go to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` and look for your file. What you have to do is look for `DocumentRoot` (it should say `/var/www/html` if you didn't change it) and change it to `YOUR_HTML_ROOT/public_html/shop` and then copy and past the same file, change the value pointing to the other site to the new.

Here is an example: 000-shop.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName shopnow.com
        ServerAlias www.shopnow.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html/shop

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And for blog: 001-blog.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName blog.shopnow.com
        ServerAlias www.blog.shopnow.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html/blog

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Remember that you must modify your DNS zone and add a `CNAME` pointing to your domain, use `@` and as value use `blog`. Also remember that you have to edit this file to match your needs.